# Usar Pattern View Model ou um method POST com Json?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Queria uma dica de vocês que são me experientes.
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que usarei propriedades de 2 *models*, qual queria a melhor opção a ser usada esse caso e se possível por gentileza liste quais são as vantagens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ViewModels

[Já dei diversas respostas sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+viewmodel), mas não falei das vantagens nelas, então vou falar de algumas.

### 1. Controle de Exposição de Variáveis

A abordagem é muito usada quando não é desejável expôr as variáveis de um *Model* diretamente mapeado em banco de dados. O *ViewModel* atua como um contêiner de dados que é tratado pelo *Controller*, o que pode evitar alguns problemas, como por exemplo a inserção de dados indevidos em banco.

### 2. Organização de Formulários

Em vários casos é desejável que um formulário tenha informações que são comuns ou divisíveis entre dois ou mais *Models*. O *ViewModel*, além de racionalizar o formulário, também oculta a estrutura interna de informações.

### 3. Montagem de Páginas de Resultados de Pesquisas

Esta é uma das minhas favoritas. Imagine uma tela de pesquisa com filtros (reporesentados por um formulário) e seus respectivos resultados.

Você pode usar um formulário que aceita o verbo `GET` e acomodar em um *ViewModel* tanto os parâmetros de pesquisa usados quanto os resultados dessa pesquisa, na forma de uma coleção ou lista. Por exemplo:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.ViewModels
{
    public class ProcessoViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Formato de Saída dos Dados")]
        public FormatoSaidaDados SaidaDados { get; set; }

        [Column("DATA_ENTRADA")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Data de Entrada Inicial")]
        public DateTime? DataEntradaInicial { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Data de Entrada Final")]
        public DateTime? DataEntradaFinal { get; set; }
        [Column("DT_DISTRIB")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Data de Distribuição Inicial")]
        public DateTime? DataDistribuicaoInicial { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Data de Distribuição Final")]
        public DateTime? DataDistribuicaoFinal { get; set; }
        [Column("DATA_ENCERRAMENTO")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Data de Encerramento Inicial")]
        public DateTime? DataEncerramentoInicial { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Data de Encerramento Final")]
        public DateTime? DataEncerramentoFinal { get; set; }

        [Column("PASTA")]
        [DisplayName("Caso Inicial")]
        public int? PastaInicial { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Caso Final")]
        public int? PastaFinal { get; set; }
        [Column("COD_CLIENTE")]
        [DisplayName("Cliente Inicial")]
        public int? ClienteIdInicial { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Cliente Final")]
        public int? ClienteIdFinal { get; set; }

        [Column("COD_REGIONAL")]
        [DisplayName("Código da Regional")]
        public String RegionalId { get; set; }
        [Column("COD_REGIONAL")]
        [DisplayName("Regionais")]
        public String[] RegionalIdMultiple { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Models.Processo> Resultados { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## 4. Serialização e Desserialização de JSON

Aqui é possivelmente onde o objetivo da sua pergunta melhor se encaixa. Serializar em JSON usando *ViewModel* é até mais vantajoso que usando apenas o *Model* por três motivos:

- Você pode estruturar o JSON usando o *ViewModel*, compondo os *Models* da maneira que desejar;
- Não tem o problema de referência circular dos *Models* ASP.NET MVC;
- Usa apenas um único comando para a serialização:

  ```
  return Json(meuViewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  ```